# How does "zuerst glühen wir vor" translate to "first, we'll have predrinks"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, german-to-english, colloquial

I found the sentence

> Zuerst glühen wir bei mir vor.

in *Memrise*. According to them, it translates to

> First, we'll have predrinks at my place.

and the literal translation

> First, glow we by me before.

My question is, how does this make sense at all? Is there any other way to say it?

Comment: Here, it is complicated by a colloquialism, but in general, if a preposition (“vor”) seems wildly out of place, check whether it is perhaps part of a *separable verb*. We have those to make learning the language more, err, interesting.

Comment: It is probably (well, definitely) not the best idea to translate German in to English word by word - and it could probably not be called literal translation.

Comment: @Ezze Confirm. *Bei mir* has nothing to do with *by me*, and the verbal part *vor* cannot be translated separately as *before*. The true 'literal' translation would be *First, we'll pre-ignite at my place* (or *pre-glow* at most). No wonder that OP thought that the sentence doesn't make sense. A translation of a correct sentence in the original language must always be a correct sentence itself. That was not the case here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

"Vorglühen" literally means "pre-glow" or "pre-ignite". The term describes the pre-heating phase when cold-starting old diesel engines.

In your context it's a slang term for the practice of drinking/sharing store-bought alcoholic beverages at home before going to a bar or club, where alcohol is much more expensive (hence "predrink"). "Pregame" would be a similar american slang term:

> Wollen wir bei mir vorglühen? - Should we pregame at my place?

Comment: I think modern diesel engines still do that (but they hide it better, like starting when opening the door or inserting key)

Comment: When I saw the question on the HNQ my first reaction was that the speaker invited everybody to a round of mulled wine (Glühwein) at his place before the office (pre-)Xmas get-together. This answer makes more sense!

Comment: Also equivalent to "pre-load" in British English slang